# AngularJS: Display table from 2D Array

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was trying to find a way to display a table from a 2D Array.  At the moment I cant get anything to display, a simple bool 1/0 is desired. Any Advice would be appreciated.

```
    var Matrix = [
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]
];


            <div id = "MatrixTable2">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody  ng-repeat="xxx in Matrix">
                    <tr width="50px">

                        <td width="50px" ng-repeat="yyy in xxx[0]"> bool {{yyy}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a `track by $index` (so that `angular` can keep track of it) and you are done :-

`*.html`

```
<table border="1">
   <tbody  ng-repeat="xxx in Matrix">
        <tr width="50px">
             <td width="50px" ng-repeat="yyy in xxx track by $index">{{yyy}}</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

`*.js`

```
$scope.Matrix = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `[0]` from `xxx[0]`:

```
ng-repeat="yyy in xxx track by $index"
```

This assumes that `Matrix` is in `$scope.Matrix`

Comment: I added the `track by $index` clause: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat